# Cant install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

Tags: apt, package-management, steam

I was trying to get wine to work and end up screwing up the system. Steam used to work but now it keeps saying I need `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` which I cant get it to install. I tried many ways and spent hours on this thing.

I tried aptitude, synaptic, `dpkg --configure -a`, `apt-get -f install`, and probably many others which I don't remember and still cant solve the broken package issue

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libudev0:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`  and `sudo apt-get update`. Then start steam again.

Comment: yup tried it before as well. didnt work